# Javascript how to let the .map() returning the new array with its initial text properties instead of numbered indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am trying to flatten a nested array of an object.

I have the following array:

```
array = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Peter',
    phone: '',
    addresses:
      [
        {
          address1: 'Manchester, UK', address2: 'London, UK'
        },
        {
          address1: 'Liverpool, UK', address2: 'NY, USA'
        }
      ]
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    name: 'Sara',
    phone: '',
    addresses: [{ address1: 'London, UK', address2: 'Paris, FR' }]
  }
];
```

The desired output should be like that:

```
array = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Peter',
    phone: '',
    addresses_address1: 'Manchester, UK',
    addresses_address2: 'London, UK'
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    name: 'Sara',
    phone: '',
    addresses_address1: 'London, UK',
    addresses_address2: 'Paris, FR'
  }
];
```

I used the `.map` and `.reduce` functions, and the example was taken from [this site](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/how-to-flatten-deeply-nested-array-of-objects-arrays-solved/171690):

```
var flatten = function (data) {
  return data.reduce(function iter(r, a) {
    if (typeof a === 'object') {
      return Object.keys(a).map(k => a[k]).reduce(iter, r);
    }
    return r.concat(a)
  }, []);
}
console.log(flatten(this.array))
```

But instead of getting the array with its text properties `id` `name`..., it get back with indexes `0`, `1`...

[image]

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-arrays-into-main-array).

Comment: it is a bit unclear, what you want the nested arrays. please add the rule.

Comment: note you also have two address objects, both with a address1 key property, in your first object under : addresses so the keys will clash on reducing them - so you will need some renaming - or precedence

Comment: @developer I can save the main properties of the array before making the changes. And yes I want them to be like `Addresses_address1: ...` and `Addresses_address2: ...`

Comment: this will merge first address down into main object.  array.map (a => Object.assign(a, a.addresses[0]))  - but i think you wanted to prepend each address with address_addressN so you will need to add a map() to rename, after or during the process

Answer (score 1):

You could take the indices as part of the property and return a new object for each element of the outer array.

```js
function flat(object, path = []) {
    return object && typeof object === 'object'
        ? Object
            .entries(object)
            .reduce((r, [k, v]) => ({ ...r, ...flat(v, [...path, k]) }), {})
        : { [path.join('-')]: object };
}

var array = [{ id: 123, name: 'Peter', phone: '', addresses: [{ address1: 'Manchester, UK', address2: 'London, UK' }, { address1: 'Liverpool, UK', address2: 'NY, USA' }] }, { id: 124, name: 'Sara', phone: '', addresses: [{ address1: 'London, UK', address2: 'Paris, FR' }] }],
    result = array.map(o => flat(o));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Go over element using map, check each object key and values.

Use `Object.entries`, If the value is of array type (Here addresses), Then build the new key-value pairs.

```js
const update = data => data.map(item =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return Object.entries(value.shift()).map(([kc, vc]) => [`${key}_${kc}`, vc]);
      } else {
        return [[key, value]];
      }
    })
  )
);

// Update: Adding alternate method to `Object.fromEntries`
const objFromEntries = arr => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach(([key, value]) => res[key] = value);
  return res;
};

const update2 = data => data.map(item =>
  objFromEntries(
    Object.entries(item).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        return Object.entries(value.shift()).map(([kc, vc]) => [`${key}_${kc}`, vc]);
      } else {
        return [[key, value]];
      }
    })
  )
);

const array = [
  {
    id: 123,
    name: "Peter",
    phone: "",
    addresses: [
      {
        address1: "Manchester, UK",
        address2: "London, UK"
      },
      {
        address1: "Liverpool, UK",
        address2: "NY, USA"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 124,
    name: "Sara",
    phone: "",
    addresses: [{ address1: "London, UK", address2: "Paris, FR" }]
  }
];


console.log(update2(array));
```

Comment: Working on stackblitz but getting an error of `Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.` on my dev environment.

Comment: Seems like the version you are using typescript or javascript does not have new API.  Try to get polyfill for this method or use the quick alternate method updated in answer.